# How to downgrade a Managed Extension Package?

Tags: managed-package, isv, versioning, managed-extension

I have a managed extension package **EXT** which is built on top of managed package BASE.

In the packaging/dev org of **EXT** 1.x I installed version 2.0 of of **BASE** to work on upcoming features of **EXT**.

By doing this I "someone mistakenly" introduced a dependency of **BASE** 2.0 into **EXT** 1.x.

**My question: Is there a way to manually set that dependancy back to an older version of base? And how would I do that?**

My initial idea was to

1. remove (comment out) all code and field dependancies in **EXT** and
2. adjust the `minorNumber` `majorNumber` in each classes `metadata.xml`.

But, is there a way to find out all dependancies to change in 1. and will 2. work?